# vba to add quotes around cell content using CHR(34) throws "sub not defined" error

Tags: excel, vba

I am tiring to write a macro so that every cell in column B gets `quote` marks around entire string in the cell

I get the error `Sub or Function not defined` and the CHAR(34) is highlighted

Thanks

Edit: This works now

```
Sub AddQuotesToCells()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = Chr(34) & cell & Chr(34)
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: It is not `CHAR()` it is `Chr()`.  Also, did you forget the `.` before the `range` at line `Set rng = range...` ?

Comment: Thanks simpLE MAn, that fixed my sub, now that it is working I see that it places B2 in each cell instead of placing `quote` marks around the content in the cells in col B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not `CHAR()` it is `Chr()`. Also, did you forget the `.` before the `range` at line `Set rng = range...`?

And for the formula question:

Change

```
rng.Formula = "=" & CHAR(34) & "B2" & CHAR(34) & ""
```

By

```
rng.Formula = "=""""""" & Chr(34) & "&" & "B2" & "&" & Chr(34) & """"""""
```

Comment: Thank You simpLE MAn, I update my post with the working macro.